# unexpected fall to if statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, fall-through

### HTML

```
<div id="main">
  <span>v</span>
  <div id="main_cursor"></div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
function highlight_word() {
  var cursor = document.getElementById(area + '_cursor'),
    pe = cursor.previousElementSibling,
    ne = cursor.nextElementSibling;
  var word = [];

  f();
  word = word.join();
  if (isInArr(keywords_arr, word)) {
    f(true);
  };

  function f(p = false) {
    while ((pe === null ? " " : pe.innerHTML) !== " " ||
      (ne === null ? " " : ne.innerHTML) !== " ") {
      if (pe !== null) {
        while (pe.innerHTML !== " ") {
          p === true ? pe.style.color = "green" : word.push(pe.innerHTML);
          pe = pe.previousElementSibling;
        }; // end of while
        word = word.reverse();
      }; //end of if
      if (ne !== null) {
        while (ne.innerHTML !== " ") {
          p === true ? pe.style.color = "green" : word.push(ne.innerHTML);
          ne = ne.nextElementSibling;
        }; //end of while
      }; //end of if
    }; // end of while
  }; // end of function f
};
```

### Objective

The objective is that first of all get the inner text of all the span which are between the `main_cursor` and a span with a space as inner text and check if the word obtain is present in the array `keywords_arr`. Is that word is present in that array then change the colour of text all those spans

or just highlight if the word is in `keyword_arr`

### Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

error is shown in the line-

```
while(pe.innerHTML!==" "){
```

and this happens only when the condition of `pe!==null` get satisfied which should not happen!

---

what should I do?

Comment: You say it should not happen, but apparently it does. The last command in the while is `pe=pe.previousElementSibling;` and then you no longer check if it's null before continuing the loop. So once it runs out of previous siblings...

Comment: are you ensuring that you're accessing only span elements? You should ensure using tagName or even document.getElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of this loop

```
while (pe.innerHTML !== " ") {
  p === true ? pe.style.color = "green" : word.push(pe.innerHTML);
  pe = pe.previousElementSibling;
}; // end of while
```

You're reassigning the value of `pe`. If `pe` no longer has any previous siblings, it will be assigned to `null`.

Instead, you could change your condition to this to ensure that `pe` is valid before checking it's `innerHTML`:

```
while (pe && pe.innerHTML !== " ") {
```